# A marker for when I've flagged a post as spam

Tags: feature-request

Spam comes in waves, and it is difficult to keep track of what I've flagged and what's new (and unflagged).  It would be nice with a little marker telling me what I've already flagged.  The marker should appear in the question list, so I don't have to open the spam to see that I've already flagged it.

(I used the downvote button as a reminder for myself, since it turns blue after its been used. But in a recent thread here in meta, somebody said that using the downvote for this purpose is depreciated.)

Comment: I always use downvote as a marker for spam questions. I see no harm in it.

Comment: It was depreciated by *kiamlaluno* in a comment below this posting: http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2398/show-pop-up-to-users-who-downvote-spam-question-to-flag-it-as-spam/2400#2400
It takes 7 spam flags to delete a spam posting, while 3 downvotes is enough to remove it from the front page.  Btw. I don't agree with him. Spam *should* be less visible. Since it still shows up in the review links for users with a rep of 125 or more, it shall be flagged as spam anyway by these reviewers.  Bit since diamond moderators are "the law" around here, I shall follow his instructions.

Comment: @GisleHannemyr Moderators don't decide about features that should be implemented; only developers do that. Personally, I am neutral about this feature request. I try to vote to close (or delete) a question I have already voted to delete more times than I try to flag as spam the same post.

Comment: I did not state (nor imply) that moderators decide about features.  I said that you, as a diamond moderator, requested that members do *not* downvote spam, and that while I disagree, I respect that request.  As for voting for deletion or closing, this is something us mere mortals here do not have the rep to do.

Comment: @GisleHannemyr I didn't make any request; I simply said that it is a bad idea because when an question's score is at least -4, only 10K users and moderators see there is a question flagged as spam. On Drupal Answers there are just 2 10K users who are not moderators. Hiding a question from the front page, you are not avoiding the question is indexed by Google.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: According to this, three *spam flags* gets it removed from the front page: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/how-does-the-spam-flag-work  So flagging also have this effect it appears.

Comment: Yes, but three spam flags have a different meaning than four down-votes. If four users would simply down-vote spam, it would not be evident there is spam. Between a single spam flag and more flags for the same question, the latter is preferable.

Comment: Yeah, but the question is not: Should I downvote *instead* of flagging?  The question is: Is  it OK to downvote *after* flagging (mainly to have a marker for self that post is already flagged)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many features requests like this have been discussed on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)

This was declined a while ago by Jeff.  From [When you flag a post, can the 'Flag' button be highlighted or something?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37147/when-you-flag-a-post-can-the-flag-button-be-highlighted-or-something)

> This would require many, many queries per page load per logged on users.

Comment: Then he should reconsider his schema.  Adding a table with pending spam flags as a relation to the user (they may be removed from this table as soon as those flags are resolved) should only generate a single query per page load per user.